# Enabling proxy caching in nginx disables 304 responses

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a weird issue where enabling proxy_caching in nginx disables 304 responses from nginx for the same requests. The server return HTTP 200 responses. 
My configuration file

```
daemon off;
pid nginx.pid;
events {}
http {
log_format serve-time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$request_time" "$http_if_modified_since"';
server {

    listen 9791 default_server;

    access_log nginx-access-log.log serve-time;
    error_log nginx-error-log.log;

    location ~/insync {
        return 200;
    }

    location ~ / {

        expires 1d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;

        # add the cache status for the response as a header
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_set_header   Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header If-Modified-Since $http_if_modified_since;
        proxy_pass http://backend;

        # use the cache configured above
        proxy_cache MY_CACHE;
        # cache only 200 Ok requests for 365 days
        proxy_cache_valid 200 365d;

    }
}
upstream backend {
    server localhost:9792;
}
proxy_cache_path nginx-cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=MY_CACHE:100m max_size=90g inactive=365d;
}
```

When cache is enabled, the server returns 200 OK responses. When I comment out proxy_cache_valid statement (which disables cache), the server returns HTTP 304 for same requests. I am issuing requests as follows

```
curl -i -H "If-Modified-Since: Thu, 28 May 2020 21:43:48 GMT" "http://localhost:9791/hello"
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It seems that nginx by-default looks for an exact match between the last modified and if-modified-since header. Setting [this property](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#if_modified_since) in the config to 'before' value fixed the issue